# Selenium- Unable to find the VerifyLocation assertion command in Chrome Extension Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide, selenium-grid

I am learning selenium, So I have this Doubt.

I notice that VerifyLocation(which verifies the URL of the site) assertion command is not available in  **chrome Extension Selenium  IDE**.

Is this normal or do I need to install anything. Can you please help me guys!!

Answer (score 0):

this is how it should be, see [documentation](https://selenium.dev/selenium-ide/docs/en/api/commands)